# How to cast date to CDT and make concatenated string using BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying the following:

```
count(distinct concat(x.my_id,cast(date_trunc('day',DATETIME(x.my_datetime,'US/Central')) as string)))
```

But I get the error:

```
Found invalid date part argument function call syntax for DATETIME()
```

When I put DATETIME(x.my_datetime,'US/Central') on its own line, it has no errors. So how can I accomplish getting the day of a datetime cast to cdt and putting it in a concatenated string?

Comment: Can you share a complete sample dataset and the expected results? Also can you share a reproducible query so the issue can be easily looked into by the community?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. `date_trunc()` should have the date/datetime/timestamp *first*, followed by the date part.
2. The date part should be the literal `day` instead of the string `'day'`.

With that in mind, your expression should be
`count(distinct concat(x.my_id,cast(date_trunc(DATETIME(x.my_datetime,'US/Central'), day) as string)))`

Comment: Note, the error message you received was because the second argument for `date_trunc()` was expecting a literal date part (day, week, month, etc), but was returning a datetime, causing the error.